# meaning of "account" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> As an example of the risk of this pursuit of novelty, Waters told me a
> story of working as a junior ad planner on the Milky Bar chocolate
> **account**, which had for many years used the well-loved Milky Bar Kid
> character in its TV advertising.

I'd like to know what 'account' means here.

Comment: Which sense given in a dictionary (try [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/account)) looks the most likely to be meant here?

Comment: He presumably was working in an ad agency or some similar business, and they had Milky Bar as a client.

Comment: In the sales field, each in-charge is given an area of products, jurisdiction, permission to work with certain organizations only.  For the salesperson, he is the account manager for that area.  In Xerox, there is a acronym KAM which means Key  Account Manager.